# Doubled chart tittle c# ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, charts

When I'm trying to add tittle to my chart as follows:

```
Chart1.Titles.Add("Test");
Chart1.Titles[0].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 26F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
Chart1.Titles[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
```

Final results is:
[image]

Why tittle is doubled?

Comment: try use Chart1.Titles.Clear(); before you add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible that it is not the title but some other control. Looking at the font size it seems that it is probably legend value. Try changing the legend value to "" and see the result.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Solution provided by @uqji is working, so is yours.

Comment: If this is the case, please upvote and accept the answer so that it can be useful to someone.